# How much memory is needed on a full-node?

Tags: iri-node, transaction, data-storage

A full-node contains all transactions from the last snapshot but I'm wondering how can it contain everything (that's a lot of data).

Does a full-node store every transaction completely? (the whole 2673 trytes?)

On average how many transactions a day are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not advice you to have a Full Node with less than 4GB of RAM at least. Also, to have it 24/7 is esential if you really wanna help the network and have a synced & usefull node. I can recommend a VPS from [Contabo](https://contabo.com/?show=configurator&vserver_id=193), used in [this tutorial](https://forum.helloiota.com/2424/Setting-up-a-VPS-IOTA-Full-Node-from-scratch) I wrote some time ago. It's working awesome and the pricing is convenient. We have several Full Nodes running with this VPS, synced and in optimal conditions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi and thanks! But can you tell me some more about storage-memory needs? I mean, a full node node has to store every transaction (from the latest snapshot). How much is it?

Comment: Since you have snapshots the database (mainnetdb) wont get to be that big. I think it was 6GB before the last snapshot. Storage is not a problem on Full Nodes with IOTA and if you have 15 GB available you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! Now I'm making some calculations: the last snapshot was on the 28th of january and the snapshot before that the 22nd of september: 4 months.
Now, 6GB are approx 4,054,405 txs (a tx should be 1589bytes) and this means 34,786 txs a day, 24 txs a minute. Is it reasonable? Am i missing something?
This means that in the whole world only 24 txs are issued a minute?
(I'm sorry if my question seems dumb but I get the mechanism but I don't get the number of people/nodes/txs involved)